# Use FileDialog folder picker for folder or zip

Tags: vba, excel, zip, directory, openfiledialog

I'm using `FileDialog` with the `msoFileDialogFolderPicker` option and what I want to do is to allow the user to browse for a zip file or a folder.

Is there any way to include zip files in this dialog and check if the clicked file is a `.zip` file or a folder in Excel VBA?

This code only gets a folder:

```
Sub browseFolder()

    Dim diaFolder As FileDialog

    ' Open the file dialog
    Set diaFolder = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    diaFolder.AllowMultiSelect = False
    diaFolder.Show

    Sheet1.filePath.Value = diaFolder.SelectedItems(1)

End Sub
```

Comment: have a look here - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff836226.aspx .  For what I recall off the top of my head the file picker wont let you select a folder as it will always go into it and display the contents so if you use  Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker) it should always be a file..

Comment: @CaptainGrumpy Yeah I'm aware of it. But is there anyway that a user can select a folder or a zipped file using one browse button only?

Comment: From everything I have seen, not easily. There appears to be a few workarounds available. https://www.codeproject.com/kb/dialog/openfileorfolderdialog.aspx it might be easier to make a userform and ask the user if they want a file or folder then use the respective picker. Or you could do a folder select and then display all valid files in that folder in a userform and let them select from there,

Comment: @CaptainGrumpy But the site only provides C# workarounds. It's not an excel VBA. Thanks.

Comment: Look at @Comintern answer - http://stackoverflow.com/a/29761436/4539709